# Why am I getting ' NameError: name '_name_' is not defined' in this code intended for Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I've just installed Flask on my computer and I am testing some code to see if Flask works. But everytime I run the following code on my computer from my command line a `NameError: name '_name_' is not defined` error appears. What is going wrong?

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(_name_)

def hello@app.route("/")
    _world() -> str:
    return "Hello world from Flask!"

app.run()
```

Comment: You missed some underscores: ``__name__`` instead of ``_name_``.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to prefixed and suffixed with two underscores, not just one!

So it's `app = Flask(__name__)` not `app = Flask(_name_)`

Answer (score 1):

it should be double underscore for `__name__`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it should be double underscore.
`__name__`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```